# InsurancePolicyParticipant Role, Financial Services Cloud StandardValueSet Naming

Tags: metadata, financial-services-cloud

I am attempting to pull the `StandardValueSet` for a multi-value picklist in Financial Services Cloud: `InsurancePolicyParticipant.Role`.

`StandardValueSet` only supports specific `<member></member>` entries (I.E. no "*" query)

Salesforce provides [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm) of `StandardValueSet` names, but not for Financial Services Cloud `StandardValueSet` instances.

Does anyone know the name of this field or how I could locate it?

It appears as `Role` in the workbench, but the following do not return any results from the metadata API:

- "InsurancePolicyParticipant.Role"
- "PolicyParticipantRole"
- "InsuranceParticipantRole"
- "ParticipantRole"
- "InsuranceRole"
- "PolicyRole"
- "InsurancePolicyParticipantRole"
- "RoleInInsurancePolicyParticipant"
- "InsurancePolicyRole"
- "Role"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce Customer Support has told me the name of the field is: `IPParticipantRole`,

Customer support also informs me that as of today this is [undocumented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_object_reference.meta/financial_services_cloud_object_reference/fsc_api_access_and_usage.htm).

This is *very frustrating* for production released enterprise product.